# How can I put many 2D numpy arrays fast in a 4D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have about 150,000 images which I want to load in a numpy array of shape `[index][y][x][channel]`. Currently, I do it like this:

```
images = numpy.zeros((len(data), 32, 32, 1))
for i, fname in enumerate(data):
    img = scipy.ndimage.imread(fname, flatten=False, mode='L')
    img = img.reshape((1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1))
    for y in range(32):
        for x in range(32):
            images[i][y][x][0] = img[0][y][x][0]
```

This works, but I think there must be a better solution than iterating over the elements. I could get rid of the reshaping, but this would still leave the two nested for-loops.

What is the fastest way to achive the same `images` 4D array, having 150,000 images which need to be loaded into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't need to copy single elements when dealing with numpy-arrays. You can just specify the axis (if they are equal sized or broadcastable) you want to copy your array to and/or from:

```
images[i,:,:,0] = img[0,:,:,0]
```

instead of your loops. In fact you don't need the reshape at all:

```
images[i,:,:,0] = scipy.ndimage.imread(fname, flatten=False, mode='L')
```

These `:` specify that you want these axis to be preserved (not sliced) and numpy supports array to array assignments, for example:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> a[0, :, :] = np.ones((3, 3))
>>> a
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

or

```
>>> a = np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> a[:, 1, :] = np.ones((3, 3))
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Not sure that that'll work with `flatten=False`, because `(x, y, 1)` won't broadcast to `(x, y)`. Isn't `images[i] = scipy.ndimage.imread(fname, flatten=False, mode='L')` enough anyway?

Comment: @Eric Good question, I assumed that [`mode='L'`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes) just defines the "bits" of the greyscale (8-bit) but will return a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there are 2 approaches

```
res = np.zeros((<correct shape>), dtype)
for i in range(...):
   img = <load>
   <reshape if needed>
   res[i,...] = img
```

If you've chosen the initial shape of `res` correctly you should be able copy each image array into its slot without loop or much reshaping.

The other approach uses list append

```
alist = []
for _ in range(...):
   img = <load>
   <reshape>
   alist.append(img)
res = np.array(alist)
```

this collects all component arrays into a list, and uses `np.array` to join them into one array with a new dimension at the start.  `np.stack` gives a little more power in selecting the `concatenation` axis.